# Sublime phpcs codesniff under Windows 10 with Joomla Standards

Tags: php, joomla, sublimetext3, phpcs

I installed everything correctly via composer and added the codesniff scripts path to the environment. When i run this on command line:

```
phpcs --report=checkstyle --standard=Joomla -n C:\xampp\htdocs\myfile.php
```

I get an correct XML codesniff output.

Problem is i cannot get it to run with Sublime 3. I installed the phpcs package and added this to the user settings:

```
{
    "show_debug": true,
    "phpcs_additional_args": {
        "--standard": "Joomla",
        "-n": ""
    }
}
```

When i try to sniff a file i get this in the console:

```
[Phpcs] phpcs --report=checkstyle --standard=Joomla -n  C:\xampp\htdocs\myfile.php
[Phpcs] phpcs --report=checkstyle --standard=Joomla -n  C:\xampp\htdocs\myfile.php
[Phpcs] cwd:  C:\xampp\htdocs\myfile.php
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 1104, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] System can't find the file

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_plugin.py", line 818, in run_
    return self.run(edit)
  File "phpcs in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Phpcs.sublime-package", line 661, in run
  File "phpcs in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Phpcs.sublime-package", line 479, in run
  File "phpcs in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Phpcs.sublime-package", line 149, in get_errors
  File "phpcs in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Phpcs.sublime-package", line 231, in execute
  File "phpcs in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Phpcs.sublime-package", line 234, in parse_report
  File "phpcs in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Phpcs.sublime-package", line 176, in shell_out
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 819, in __init__
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 1110, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] System can't find the file
```

Comment: wow, joomla has standards? anyway, sounds like a broken plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was:

1. Although i had the phpcs path environment variable set and i could call the phpcs commands from everywhere i had to set `phpcs_executable_path` to a full path like

   `"phpcs_executable_path": 
   "c:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Roaming\\Composer\\vendor\\squizlabs\\php_codesniffer\\scripts\\phpcs.bat"`

---

2. I had to add the `--no-patch` arg to phpcbf because of the none existence of the `diff` command under vanilla windows like this

`"phpcbf_additional_args": {
        "--standard": "Joomla",
        "--no-patch": "",
        "-n": ""
    },`

---

3. I had to edit the phpcs.bat file and replace `@php_bin@` with the full path to PHP executable. Somehow during composer Prozess those should get replaced but it did not happen:

   `if "%PHPBIN%" == "" set PHPBIN=c:\xampp\php\php.exe`

So a lot of crap to be done. Seams to me windows is not that well supported during all the installation processes.